# Lombok and Web services: A WSDL Definition could not be generated for the implementation class

Tags: java, web-services, wsdl, jax-ws, lombok

I'm using IBM Rational Developer and Websphere Application Server

I'm developing a java web service (with jax-ws) through annotations in an enterprise application, I have an EJB project, a Web Project where the web service is published and an EAR that holds both modules. When I deploy the EAR to WAS, I get this error message:

```
[26/05/17 16.37.38:254 CEST] 00000057 WSModuleDescr E   WSWS7027E: Impossibile creare correttamente le descrizioni del servizio JAX-WS a causa del seguente errore: javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: WSWS7054E: Impossibile generare il file WSDL (Web Services Description Language) per la classe di implementazione del servizio Web it.bz.prov.as400.personal.logic.AnagraficaImpl a causa del seguente errore: java.lang.Exception: A WSDL Definition could not be generated for the implementation class: it.bz.prov.as400.personal.logic.AnagraficaImpl
at com.ibm.ws.websvcs.wsdl.WASWSDLGenerator.generateWsdl(WASWSDLGenerator.java:262)
at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.description.impl.EndpointDescriptionImpl.generateWSDL(EndpointDescriptionImpl.java:2084)
at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.description.impl.EndpointDescriptionImpl.<init>(EndpointDescriptionImpl.java:434)
at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.description.impl.ServiceDescriptionImpl.<init>(ServiceDescriptionImpl.java:401)
at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.description.impl.ServiceDescriptionImpl.<init>(ServiceDescriptionImpl.java:297)
at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.description.impl.DescriptionFactoryImpl.createServiceDescriptionFromDBCMap(DescriptionFactoryImpl.java:273)
at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.description.DescriptionFactory.createServiceDescriptionFromDBCMap(DescriptionFactory.java:524)
at com.ibm.ws.websvcs.desc.WSModuleDescriptorImpl.buildJAXWSServices(WSModuleDescriptorImpl.java:1364)
at com.ibm.ws.websvcs.desc.WSModuleDescriptorImpl._containsJAXWSWebServices(WSModuleDescriptorImpl.java:538)
at com.ibm.ws.websvcs.desc.WSModuleDescriptorImpl.containsJAXWSWebServices(WSModuleDescriptorImpl.java:513)
at com.ibm.ws.webservices.admin.utils.ServiceContainmentHelper.<init>(ServiceContainmentHelper.java:71)
at com.ibm.ws.webservices.admin.utils.CommonUtils.getServiceContianmentHelper(CommonUtils.java:690)
at com.ibm.ws.webservices.admin.utils.CommonUtils.hasWebServices(CommonUtils.java:295)
at com.ibm.ws.webservices.admin.utils.CommonUtils.hasJAXWSWebServices(CommonUtils.java:238)
at com.ibm.ws.webservices.admin.deploy.DeploymentValidation.getWebServiceType(DeploymentValidation.java:309)
at com.ibm.ws.webservices.admin.deploy.DeploymentValidation.validateEarModules(DeploymentValidation.java:381)
at com.ibm.ws.webservices.admin.deploy.DeploymentValidation.validateTargetForPartialUpdate(DeploymentValidation.java:1182)
at com.ibm.ws.webservices.admin.deploy.ServiceIndexServerTask.performTask(ServiceIndexServerTask.java:168)
at com.ibm.ws.management.application.SchedulerImpl.run(SchedulerImpl.java:315)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:790)
Caused by: java.lang.Exception: A WSDL Definition could not be generated for the implementation class: it.bz.prov.as400.personal.logic.AnagraficaImpl
    at com.ibm.ws.websvcs.wsdl.WASWSDLGenerator.generateWsdl(WASWSDLGenerator.java:242)
    ... 19 more
```

I do not use maven nor ant to build the project.

After long (ugh) research, i found out that the error message arises when there are problems with indirect dependencies in the web module for the classes used for the web service, i.e. the implementation of the web service in the EJB project makes use of a jar that itself depends on another jar that isn't provided. 
Specifically, this problem arises when I put a lombok annotation (e.g. @Data or @Getter) in a class that is used by the web service implementation.

What baffles me is that the web service works perfectly, as does everything else. I just have this stack trace every time I deploy the project to WAS.
So, the questions: 
- do I have to worry about this error message?
- how do I get rid of it? I could add to the classpath all jars that lombok dependends on, but I would prefer not to (also because I can't seem to find a list of dependencies for lombok)

Thanks, and sorry for my bad english

Answer (score 0):

Lombok does not have any dependencies.

Do you use any tools that process the source code?

Disclosure: I am a lombok developer.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure what you mean with "tools that process the source code"? I use IBM's Rational Application Developer (which is based on Eclipse) to write the code, build from there and deploy on websphere from there (with the integrated "server" view of RAD).